# Django modelManager - can not see instances/objects in View/listview - no erroer

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am new to django. I am trying to display with a `models.Manager` only the `published=True` instances. In the terminal no error comes. What I am doing wrong? I have a feeling it has something to do with my view.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class BlogPostManager(models.Manager):

    use_for_related_fields = True
    def freetosee(self, **kwargs):
        return self.filter(published=True, **kwargs)

class Post(models.Model):
    NOT_RATED = 0
    RATED_G = 1
    RATED_PG = 2
    RATED_R = 3

    RATINGS =(
        (NOT_RATED, 'NR-Not Rated'),
        (RATED_G, 'G - General Audience'),
        (RATED_PG, 'Parental'),
        (RATED_R, 'Restriced'),
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    body = models.TextField()
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    rating = models.IntegerField(
        choices=RATINGS,
        default=NOT_RATED,
    )
    objects = BlogPostManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
from .models import Post


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    template_name = 'postlist.html'
```

**template**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% for post in posts.objects.freetosee %}
        {{ post.title }} - {{ post.body }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .views import PostListView

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
    path('list/', PostListView.as_view(), name='post-list'),
]
```

I expect to see all models instances in the `ListView` with `published=True`

Comment: what's the django version you're using?

Comment: since you provide context_object_name in views.py so you don't need to write posts.objects.freetosee while looping instead write posts only

Comment: Iam using django version 2.1 @xxbinxx

Comment: @RobertF. Check answer, does that work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how it works. `posts` is a queryset, it doesn't have an `objects` attribute. You need to call that in the view:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.freetosee()
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    template_name = 'postlist.html'
```

and then in your template just do `{% for post in posts %}`

Comment: Thanks for you advice. I will try that. Just for future understanding: all querysets i need to put in the view and it wont work to call it in the templates, i understand that right? Can i put filters in templates? Thank you very much. Sorry for all the questions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using 2.1
As per [django 2.0 deprecation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-2-0) `use_for_related_fields = True` is **removed**
You'll have to use `base_manager_name` in model `Meta`. like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # your fields here
    objects = BlogPostManager()

    class Meta:
        base_manager_name = 'objects'
```

As suggested above in comments, when you have `context_object_name` set you don't have to do `posts.objects.freetouse`

Change your template to:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        {{ post.title }} - {{ post.body }}
    {% endfor %}    
{% endblock %}
```

from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering): the `ListView` has a `get_queryset()` method we can override. Previously, it has just been returning the value of the `queryset` attribute, but now we can add more logic.

This means you can do

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.freetosee()
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    template_name = 'postlist.html'
```

and you can also do:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    template_name = 'postlist.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        # this method can be used to apply as many filters as you want
        # Just a quick example, 
        # filter_id = self.request.GET.get('filter_by')
        # if filter_id:
        #     return Post.objects.filter(id=filter_id)
        return Post.objects.freetosee()
```

**NOTE:** Please understand `Views` are there to handle all data and pass it to `templates`. You make `managers` to keep your custom queries methods in one place. So it's one place for one kind of thing also your template should not make any query request unless it's super necessary. `templates` are just to display. If you want `filters` in `templates` use template tags. That will keep your code clean and readable.